# Optimize $x^2+y^2+y-1$ subject to $x^2+y^2\leq1$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I´ve been trying to solve this optimization problem using Lagrange methods. Analizing the interior of the domain, it is clear that it has a mínimum on $(0,-0.5)$. But analizing along the border, I found out the point $(0,1)$ using lagrange. The hessian matrix is positive definite so that point is a minimun too. But I´m not sure if what I did is correct. Is there another critical point?

Answer (score 1):

With $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2+y-1$, follows the lagrangian

$$
L(x,y,\lambda,s) = f(x,y)+\lambda(x^2+y^2-1+s^2)
$$

Here $s$ is a slack variable to transform the inequality into an equation. The stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = \cases{2x+2\lambda x = 0\\ 2y+1+2\lambda y = 0\\ x^2+y^2-1+s^2=0\\ \lambda s = 0}
$$

giving

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
f& x & y & \lambda & s^2\\
 -\frac{5}{4} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{3}{4} \\
 -1 & 0 & -1 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{3}{2} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Follows a plot showing the level curves for $f(x,y)$ in black, the feasible region in light blue and the stationary points in red. Note that $s=0$ at the frontier points.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your reply was very useful. I would like to ask you if I´m using the bordered hessian matrix properly to qualify points. 

\begin{matrix}
    0 & 2x & 2y \\
   2x &2 & 0 \\
  2y & 0 & 2 \\
    \end{matrix}

Comment: No need for bordered Hessian.  Look at the stationary points (in red). At top and bottom we have two vectors. In red, the normal pointing to the feasible region interior and in black, the objective function minimizing gradient. In both cases, the points can slid along the feasible region, to a lower value point hence those two points are not minimizers. The only minimizer is the point located at $(0,-\frac 12)$.